How to include folders without top level __init__.py in wheel file
Say I have this:
rodrigocarvajal@rodrigos-MBP wheel_tests % tree .
.
├── MyStuff
│   └── my_module_2
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── hello_world.py
├── MyStuff.pth
├── my_module
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── hello_world.py
└── setup.py

Where setup.py is:
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
import setuptools

setup(name='test',
      version='0.1',
      description='Tool to learn ip addresses on a network.',
      author='someone',
      author_email='...',
      packages=find_packages(where='.')
      )

I want to make a wheel file. So I do python3 setup.py bdist_wheel, and the dir now looks like this:
rodrigocarvajal@rodrigos-MBP wheel_tests % tree .                      
.
├── MyStuff
│   └── my_module_2
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── hello_world.py
├── MyStuff.pth
├── build
│   ├── bdist.macosx-10.9-universal2
│   └── lib
│       └── my_module
│           ├── __init__.py
│           └── hello_world.py
├── dist
│   └── test-0.1-py3-none-any.whl
├── my_module
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── hello_world.py
├── setup.py
└── test.egg-info
    ├── PKG-INFO
    ├── SOURCES.txt
    ├── dependency_links.txt
    └── top_level.txt

My question is, how do I tell the wheel command to read the .pth file so that my_module_2 also gets added to the top level of the wheel?

Nope, no way. Moving my_module_2 out of MyStuff is the only way.
